# Printing Issue in Dot Matrix Printer

Tags: html, css, dot-matrix

I have no problem printing a html invoice using firefox in macbook (osx). But, when I tried in firefox in windows 7 and windows 10 it have an issue. It is not print the line for table.

I have tried to change the css to fix the issue, but it is failed. This is several methods that I've tried :

- change the border to be bolder (from 1px solid to 4px solid), but it is still not print the line
- set the printing properties and printing preferences
- change border from solid to dashed, dotted. this is just to test if I can print a line in different pattern

I also tried this to check if there is a problem with the printer or not :

- print table using microsoft excel in windows 7. it print the table properly, all lines printed. (no problem to print table from excel)
- save the web page into pdf, then print it in windows 7, not all line printed. only bottom line and top line which is printed

Any ideas ?

Thank you

I am using Bootstrap 4 and this css :

```
/* Chrome 2.0+, IE 8.0+, Opera 6.0+ and Safari 5.0+*/
@page {
    size: auto;
    /*size: 5.5in 8.5in;*/
    margin:10px 5px 0 15px;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}

/* For Firefox */
@media {
    html, body {
        /*width: 215mm;*/
        /*height: 139.7mm;*/
        width:98%;
        margin:7px 0 0 5px;
    }

    body {
        font-size: 12pt;
        letter-spacing: 3pt;
        line-height: 1.2;
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    }

    p, div{
        font-size: 12pt;
        letter-spacing: 3pt;
    }

    table th, .table th{
        padding: 0.45rem .75rem;
        line-height: 1;
    }

    table td, .table td{
        padding: 0.35rem .75rem;
        line-height: 1;
    }

    hr{
        margin: 0.5rem 0;
    }

    .container-fluid{
        padding: 0;
    }

    .col-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12{
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are CSS media queries that target the print view of a page. Could you paste your print media query here?

Comment: I have add the css, it have no problem when I print it from firefox in OSX.